# Using compass with Yeoman project, but outside of Yeoman server

Tags: compass-sass, yeoman

I'm circumventing the built-in Yeoman server and severing files directly from the /app directory. Since Yeomen's server manages compass/sass compliation I'm having a hard time running compass outside of it. Running the compass cli directly doesn't work; it's not aware that it's in an existing compass project. So I get:

```
$ compass watch /app (or /app/styles)
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
```

Has anybody had experience getting this to work?

Comment: I have a similar situation; I'm introducing Yeoman to a project that requires IIS. Looking forward to seeing how to solve this problem.

Comment: `yeoman compass` will execute the configuration set in GruntFile.js. Or that's not what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your Compass settings out into a [`config.rb` file](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) to use the Compass CLI.

However, you can easily run the Compass grunt task individually like so `grunt compass` to compile, or `grunt watch` to automagically compile on file changes.